# UPDATE and SELECT ORDER in two differents tables

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update row with two differents tables

```
UPDATE produits p set p.quantite_produit_commande
FROM (

SELECT
p.id_produit,
p.nom_produit,
(p.quantite_produit_commande) as "stock" ,
(SUM(lc.quantite))  as "ordered quantity" ,
(p.quantite_produit_commande -  SUM(lc.quantite)) as remaining_stock
FROM produits p
INNER JOIN lignes_commandes lc ON lc.id_produit = p.id_produit
GROUP BY p.id_produit)
WHERE p.id_produit = 1;
```

but i have an error of syntax

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'FROM ( SELECT...

help please!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: ?? `set p.quantite_produit_commande` TO WHAT?

Comment: thanks for answer:
to this : p.quantite_produit_comman= p.quantite_produit_commande -  SUM(lc.quantite)

Comment: `UPDATE` doesn't even have `FROM` in it's syntax.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for answers,
I made this, and it works.
      `UPDATE produits p set p.quantite_produit_stock= ( SELECT 
        (p.quantite_produit_stock - SUM(lc.quantite)) as stock_restant 
                FROM produits p INNER JOIN lignes_commandes lc 
                ON lc.id_produit = p.id_produit inner join commandes c on 
               c.id_commande=lc.id_commande and lc.id_produit=p.id_produit and 
               p.id_produit = ? 
                GROUP BY p.id_produit ) 
                where p.id_produit=?`

Answer (score 0):

The `Update` query doesn't work just by adding a `select`.

Try the below query to update

```
UPDATE produits AS p
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        id_produit, SUM(quantite) AS sum_quantite
    FROM
        lignes_commandes
    GROUP BY id_produit) AS lc ON p.id_produit = lc.id_produit 
SET 
    p.quantite_produit_commande = (p.quantite_produit_commande - lc.sum_quantite)
WHERE
    p.id_produit = 1;
```

For more info you can refer the docs [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)